# How to fix this errors and how to put tools to toolbox

Tags: c#, winforms, bunifu

First time use Bunifu , I used Basic Bunifu152.dll . Now I have downloaded the full Bunifu software on nuget , and i don't know add it to toolbox , i did somethings and the result is 129 errors .Im very worry about my project .Hope you can help me

**Error**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU67m.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNNrC.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry , this is second times i post into here , so I'm just a newbie

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have two libraries with the same controls in the project. To fix this, remove one of that libraries. In your case, remove the reference to the dll and use only the nuget package.